# Should a (small) site ever use both an SQL and a noSQL database

Tags: mysql, database, nosql

I'm building a site which will, as a component, have a chat feature. The site uses a MySQL database, but I've read that chat logs shouldn't be stored in MySQL because extracting the logs from an SQL database is resource-intensive.

Since the chat logs are fairly low-priority data, all of the tradeoffs which come with NoSQL databases are acceptable, but I've never come across a small system which used two databases. Is there any particular reason I shouldn't? Or am I just vastly overoptimising and should store the logs in the MySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

Questions are too broad but to summarise:

There's no reason you can't use two SQL + NoSQL DBs together. Note that "Chat logs" can get big pretty fast so prepare in advance to be able to delete old chats if required. Also, keeping them separate has the added advantage of not having the less important db (NoSQL chat logs) slow down the performance of features provided by your more important db (MySQL db for the site).

Your constraints are more likely to come from your hosting provider (space usage, total db's available, etc.). And I do hope you are going to inform your visitors that chats are being logged.

Comment: Hosting isn't something I'd considered actually, cheers. And the logs are for user access, they'll know they're there, but fair point.

Answer (score 0):

You must think about how many db records you'll insert to database per day? If it's not like 100k per day, MySql can easily take care of that. Otherwise MySql can handle more data but you must take care of some other things like hardware speed (ssd) and db configurations.

Of course you can use multiple dbs but if we are talking about Big Data, you should consider everything, not only db software.